# Append columns to an array

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

This may sound fundamental problem but i'm totally blocked finding an efficient solution that has no performance impact on my application

I have a dynamic 2D array that i don't know the size of it at init time

```
object[,] 2d = GetData();
```

Then i have a for loop, each loop return one dimensional array with same number of rows as the 2d one.

```
foreach (var col in externalData)
{
  // here append to 2d array
}
```

Do i have to create a new array and copy all for each loop? or is there a faster solution?
I'm sure there is a simple solution that i cannot think of.

**EDIT:**

Example, The value of the 2d array is

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
4 5 5
1 1 1
```

then let us say that the for loop generates 2 arrays

```
6
5
4
2
```

and

```
4
5
2
2
```

Now i want to append the 2 results of the for loop to the the 2D array
so that the resault at the end should be like

```
1 2 3 6 4
4 5 6 5 5
4 5 5 4 2
1 1 1 2 2
```

What is important also is that the final result should be type of `object[,]`

Comment: how is that one dimensional array related to your 2D array, show the data structure with illustration

Comment: Your situation isn't clear, but if you want to be adding objects to a collection then I suggest you use a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of an array. A list of lists?.. maybe. Or create a class for your data and have a list of them, depends of what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general use a jagged array instead of a multi-dimensional array but,

since you don't know the size of at intialization, don't use an array.

How about, for your example,

```
var twoD = new List<List<int>>
    {
       { 1, 2, 3 }
       { 4, 5, 6 }
       { 4, 5, 5 }
       { 1, 1, 1 }
    }
```

instead.

---

Then you could use a generic extension like,

```
void AddColumn(this List<List<T>> source, IList<T> column)
{
   if (column is null)
   {
       throw new ArgumentNullException("column");
   }

   if (column.Count != source.Count)
   {
       throw new ArgumentException("column");
   }

   for(var i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
   {
       source[i].Add(column[i]);
   }
}
```

To add a column. Like this,

```
twoD.AddColumn(new[]
    {
        6,
        5,
        4,
        2
    });
```

---

Then when your are finished with your manipulations, you could use

```
object[,] ToMultiObject<T>(this IList<IList<T>> source)
{
    var x = source.Max(r => r.Count);
    var y = source.Count;

    var result = new object[x, y];
    for (var i = 0, i < source.Count, i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0, j < source[i].Count, j++)
        {
            result[j, i] = source[i][j];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What is important also is that the final result should be type of object[,]

Comment: By adding new 'List<int>' is you adding a new row but not column

Comment: @Maro, you are mistaken.